# how do i only allow numeric input in react for example if someone tries to copy paste text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i want to only allow text input no copy pasting in text

i've already made it that the numeric keyboard should open but i want to only allow numbers in this input field period

```
<TextInput
         underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
         style={styles.TextInputStyle}
         placeholder='0.00'
         keyboardType={'numeric'}
         value={this.state.shippingCharge}
         onChangeText={(shippingCharge) => this.setState({ shippingCharge })}
     />
```

Comment: Update state after check with `isNaN(parseFloat(shippingCharge))` when textinput is changed.

Comment: @BrunoMazzardo I think OP is looking for checking both integer and float not only integer.

Comment: yes both integer and float

Comment: Anyway, Idan answer with some adjustment should do the trick.

Comment: where in my App.js file should i put

Comment: onChangeTextInput = (text) => {
         const numericRegex = /^([0-9]{1,100})+$/
         if (numericRegex.test(text)) {
             this.setState({ shippingCharge: text }
         }
     }

Comment: just copy Idan answer, and paste it to your codebase

Comment: also im getting a error for the second to last } saying unexpected and its fatel

Comment: Copy and paste before `render` function in your component.

Comment: You probably just forgot to copy one {, or deleted one. Paste your entire code here..

Comment: SyntaxError: C:\Users\arich\Documents\efees\App.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (73:6)

  71 |       if(numericRegex.test(text)) {
  72 |           this.setState({ shippingCharge: text }
> 73 |       }
     |       ^
  74 |   }
  75 |
  76 |  render() {
Failed building JavaScript bundle.

Comment: that's the error i'm getting i copy and pasted all the code and placed it before the render

Comment: It's the error because of missing `)`, add `)` as `this.setState({ shippingCharge: text })`.

Comment: How do you check for decimals?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `Regex` validation on input (numeric with maximum length 100 numbers for example):

```
<TextInput
     underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
     style={styles.TextInputStyle}
     placeholder='0.00'
     keyboardType={'numeric'}
     value={this.state.shippingCharge}
     onChangeText={this.onChangeTextInput}
 />



onChangeTextInput = (text) => {
    const numericRegex = /^([0-9]{1,100})+$/
    if(numericRegex.test(text)) {
        this.setState({ shippingCharge: text })
    }
}
```

Comment: but i already have an action being done with on change text can i have 2 onchangetext's in one textInput field

Comment: @prog you tried my code? it's doing what you said

Comment: You can't have two onChangeText function, but you can merge their code. Other way is to split in validation and action, then call it both on other function.

Comment: onChangeTextInput = (text) => {
    const numericRegex = /^([0-9]{1,100})+$/
    if(numericRegex.test(text)) {
        this.setState({ shippingCharge: text }
    }
}

Comment: where should i place that chunk of code

Comment: @BrunoMazzardo how do i merge the code

Comment: @prog you can do that like my code, you take the merge code to outside function (but inside the class) and when the input will change the function are calling

Comment: @prog if you don't wanna separate the code to more function you can do this: 
`onChangeText={(shippingCharge)=> { (/^([0-9]{1,100})+$/).test(shippingCharge) ? this.setState({ shippingCharge }) : null } }`

Comment: There's typo, missing `)` after `this.setState({ shippingCharge: text }`.

Comment: @Antonio my bad, i will fix it

Comment: @prog it helps?

Comment: it helped with that textinput but how should i apply it to my other text inputs and also its causing some problems with my app

Comment: i think the main problem is it does not let me change delete the entered number because i guess thats consider whitespace so it just dosent let be hit backspace on that text input

Comment: @prog You can attach all class code? and what exactly not working ?